# JQuery - Return ID of dropped list item

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, return, drag, attr

I am trying to return "id" when dropping and item from the list. I have tried variations of this.id and $(item).attr('id'). The examples I've come across work fine with their small examples but not with my chop suey.

The areas I think are relevant:

```
  $(function () {
    $("#items li").draggable();
    $(".squaredotted").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var item = $(item).attr('id');  // Want to return "id" here...
                $("#info").html("dropped: " + item);
    });
});
```

and

```
        for (var l = 0; l <= curr; l++) {
        var pos = list[l];
        $('#items').append('<li id=' + String(l) + ' class="list">' + String(l) + ' - ' + String(list[l]) + '</li>');
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y3dsvmcp/1/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ui.draggable.attr("id")` instead.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!